# How to create a chapter with a custom name that shows up on the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I have sort of an extreme problem:

In my document, I have the following chapter:

```
\chapter{Addendum A: random facts}
```

which creates
[image]

Obviously, this is higly undesirable, as I now have two titles for the chapter.

What I want is just for the title to be "Addendum A..." as below
[image]

To resolve this issue, it is simple: just put a star after \chapter

```
\chapter*{Addendum A: random facts}
```

Done, no more Chapter 1.

But wait a minute, I also have a table of content!!

Adding the * makes the chapter no longer show up in the table of content!!

[image]

**Does anyone know how I can change the name of the chapter AND make it show up on the table of contents? **

Thanks, code blow:

```
%% *** Add any desired options. ***
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Addendum A: random facts}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A\arabic{section}}
\section{The origin of 1}

\begin{equation}
    1  = 0 + 1
\end{equation}

\section{The origin of 2}

\begin{equation}
    2  = 0 + 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `\chapter*{Addendum A: random facts} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Addendum A: random facts}`...

Comment: @Werner I was sort of hoping for a solution whereby I don't need to put a * after \Chapter to suppress "Chapter 1", but simply change "Chapter 1" to "Addendum A". This way I don't have to mess with the table of content

Comment: That's not clear from your question. You should provide an image of what you're after, since purely removing `Chapter 1` seems to be insufficient. You want `Chapter 1` replaced with `Addendum A`. Also, like `A` is to `1`, would `C` be to `3`?

Comment: No need for the "A" to be automatic, just whatever is between the brackets of \chapter{...}.

Comment: The placement of `Chapter 1` is also different from the placement of the actual title. So how should that be handled?

Comment: @ProcrastinationSage: Your setup uses `A` for the section and equation number, how should TeX know what you want to have for next addendum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Addendum' is  something like an appendix, so `\appendix` before `\chapter*{}` does most of the counter and anchor setup, the final issue is the the ToC entry, which can be achieved with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Addendum \thechapter: your title}
```

However, this can get tedious if more than one of such addendum chapters are desired.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Normal chapter}

\section{Foo section}

\appendix
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\chapter*{Addendum A: random facts}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Addendum \thechapter: random facts}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A\arabic{section}}
\section{The origin of 1}

\begin{equation}
    1  = 0 + 1
\end{equation}

\section{The origin of 2}

\begin{equation}
    2  = 0 + 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Other solution with `\backmatter`**

The addition of chapter titles to the ToC is still applied if `\@mainmatterfalse` holds, i.e. in case of `\backmatter`, however, there is no chapter counter stepping, so this has to be reenabled.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Normal chapter}

\section{Foo section}

\appendix
\preto{\chapter}{\refstepcounter{chapter}}% Add stepping again

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\backmatter

\chapter{Addendum A: random facts}
\section{The origin of 1}

\begin{equation}
    1  = 0 + 1
\end{equation}

\section{The origin of 2}

\begin{equation}
    2  = 0 + 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution where I don't have to put a * after \Chapter, and still can change Chapter 1 -> Addendum A?

Comment: @ProcrastinationSage: Found a shorter way, with `\backmatter`